# Problems testing with @Capture Mockito

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to test the SftpSession.read method with junit, I am not pretty sure of what is the way to test this method, I am using an @Captor, but I don't have clearly understanding of can I implement this test. This is the code of my test:

```
@Test
void getFileContent() throws IOException {
    String directory = "testDirectory";
    String fileName = "testFileName";
    ByteArrayOutputStream fileByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    given(sessionFactory.getSession()).willReturn(sftpSession);

    sftpServiceImpl.getFileContent(directory, fileName);

    verify(sftpSession, times(1)).read(captor.capture(), eq(fileByteStream));
}
```

This is the getFileContent method:

```
@Override
    public byte[] getFileContent(String directory, String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (SftpSession session = sessionFactory.getSession()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream fileByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            session.read(directory + "/" + fileName, fileByteStream);
            return fileByteStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
verify(sftpSession, times(1)).read(any(String.class), any(ByteArrayOutputStream.class));
```

or

```
verify(sftpSession, times(1)).read(argThat (arg -> arg.contains(directory) && arg.contains(fileName) ), argThat (arg -> arg != null));
```